# 19.10: Login screen does not close after waking up

Tags: login, gdm

I have freshly installed Ubuntu 19.10. Aside from the standard install I have installed Insync and Dropbox. I used symlink to have my Dropbox files stored on my secondary hard drive.

After my computer goes to sleep I waken it by hitting the enter key and the login comes up. I enter my credentials and hit the enter key again. I then get the normal screen, by which I mean icons on the left and on the top of the screen. However, the login dialog box does not close and remains open and visible.

I cannot display any programs and thus can do no work of any kind. If I click on an icon to open a program the icon shows the program as running but I cannot get to it.

Any suggestions from anyone?

Thanks

Comment: 1) What happens if you switch to another window? https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-windows-switching.html.en 2) Are you using the default Gnome Display Manager 3? https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/12/how-to-change-default-display-manager.html Please click [edit] and answer 1) and 2).  Please don't answer with Add Comment; instead, please use [edit].

Comment: It happened to me once. It is not an actual window, but kind of ghost image. The only option was to log out and re-log in. I could have tried refreshing desktop (Alt+F2 r Enter).